# Use Watsons Lemma to find the asymptotic expansion

Tags: integration, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

Use Watson's Lemma to obtain the first 2 terms in the asymptotic expansion as $x\rightarrow \infty$ of $\int^{\infty}_{0}e^{-xt}cost \ dt$

I have so far that $I(x)=\int^{\epsilon}_{0}e^{-xt}cost \ dt+\int^{\infty}_\epsilon e^{-xt}cost \ dt$

Then, $I(x) \sim \int^{\epsilon}_{0}e^{-xt}cost \ dt$

Introduce rescaled variable $s=xt$ and $\dfrac{ds}{dt}=x$
Then $I(x) \sim \dfrac{1}{x}\int^{\epsilon x}_{0}cos(\dfrac{s}{x})e^{-s} ds$

Where do I go from here?

I have the taylor series expansion $cos \ t=1-\dfrac{1}{2}t^2+\dfrac{1}{24}t^4-...$

And I know at some point I will use the standard integral $\int^{\infty}_{0}s^{2n}e^{-s}ds = (2n)!$

I also know that by Watson's Lemma, $I(x) \sim \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\dfrac{a_n\Gamma(\alpha + \beta_n + 1)}{x^{\alpha + \beta_n + 1}}$

Comment: Why did you split the integral in the first place? Just check the conditions for Watsons lemma and apply.

Comment: Im not sure how to check the conditions for Watsons lemma or apply it

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson%27s_lemma#Statement_of_the_lemma). Essentially, you want to check that 1. $g(t) = \cos(t)$ has an expansion around $t = 0$ 2. $g(0) \ne 0$ 3. $\lambda > -1$ and is real (in your case, $\lambda = 0$) 4. $|t^{\lambda} g(t)| \lt Ke^{ct}$ for some constants $K$ and $c$. If your integrand satisfies these conditions, then you can go ahead and use the series solution you have written in your post, though I think you are better off using the form of the series in the wiki article I linked.